# Sitefinity REST/oData to create image with Category and Tags

Tags: web-services, odata, sitefinity

I am trying to post the image in Sitefinity using postman. I am able to do so but I would like to add the Category & Tags to the image. In body i am giving base64 image value and in header i am giving other properties like:

```
X-Sf-Properties: {"ParentId":"643a330f-2c29-4b6a-ad75-16dd14a2b76a", "Title":"NewImage", "UrlName":"{{$guid}}"}
```

To add the category i change my property field to this but it does not work

```
X-Sf-Properties: {"ParentId":"643a330f-2c29-4b6a-ad75-16dd14a2b76a", "Title":"NewImage", "UrlName":"{{$guid}}", "Category":["c0e7d8c4-d5ef-4a1b-b020-129f42af96ad","68544ae9-bf2f-4e69-ae25-9c2f1de60254","49fc1413-2f10-49b6-8a78-d02285166abb"]}
```

Once i succeeded with postman i will be creating console application to import my data into sitefinity 10

Also i tried another approach of posting json data but no luck

Headers:

```
Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q....
Content-Type:application/json
```

Body:

```
{
  "Title": "sample string 2",
  "Description": "sample string 3",
  "UrlName": "{{$guid}}",
  "Author": "sample string 6",
  "AlternativeText": "sample string 7",
  "ParentId": "4ba7ad46-f29b-4e65-be17-9bf7ce5ba1fb",
  "file": {"filename":"image1.png", "contents":"...base64encodevalue...."}
}
```

but i am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Please see attached Success & Failure screen shots. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

[Post Image Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe5nN.png)
[Post Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24Y9v.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the example given in the use in my app docs you can see the json should be formatted like below for posting an image. For your Category array the name is incorrect (Category[]) and you are passing an object {} with no name/value pair.  Should just be passing an array of Guid as a string ["4ba7ad46-f29b-4e65-be17-9bf7ce5ba1fb","4ba7ad46-f29b-4e65-be17-9bf7ce5ba1fb"]

---

[image]

[image]

```
{
  "PublicationDate": "2018-06-14T14:34:32.4964905Z",
  "ExpirationDate": "2018-06-14T14:34:32.4964905Z",
  "Title": "sample string 2",
  "Description": "sample string 3",
  "Ordinal": 4.1,
  "UrlName": "sample string 5",
  "Author": "sample string 6",
  "Category": [
    "951935ce-9a30-4e8d-9741-9682f2b0fc82",
    "2e9c31a5-025f-4981-bda4-665773e098ff"
  ],
  "Tags": [
    "c9f6e7c2-0434-4041-bc7a-d14e67b74dae",
    "76fe88dc-2601-49b7-965b-abb7f35c45c4"
  ],
  "AlternativeText": "sample string 7",
  "FolderId": "6414114c-f40b-48e8-a27e-18a1ebf1aa72",
  "ParentId": "b22d8be8-a7b0-4bf7-afcb-e3c208ed3baa"
}
```